# Using a sub query in a where clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, subquery, where-clause

I need to have the results from this reports only show patients with a status of I. Not really sure how to do it where this report is so sub query heavy with a lot of them being correlated. Not sure if I could put a sub query in a where statement that would blanket the entire thing. Thanks in advance for any help. SQL Server 2005

```
SELECT patient_id,
   (
       SELECT p.case_status
       FROM   patient p
       WHERE  p.patient_id = btb.patient_id
              AND p.episode_id = (
                      SELECT MAX(episode_id)
                      FROM   patient p2
                      WHERE  p2.patient_id = p.patient_id
                  )
   )                            AS 'Status',
   (
       SELECT p.lname + ', ' + p.fname
       FROM   patient p
       WHERE  p.patient_id = btb.patient_id
              AND p.episode_id = (
                      SELECT MAX(episode_id)
                      FROM   patient p2
                      WHERE  p2.patient_id = p.patient_id
                  )
   )                            AS 'client',
   Coverage_plan_id,
   (
       SELECT proc_code
       FROM   billing_transaction bt
       WHERE  bt.clinical_transaction_no = btb.clinical_transaction_no
              AND bt.coverage_plan_id = btb.coverage_plan_id
              AND bt.coverage_plan_id = btb.coverage_plan_id
   )                            AS 'Procedure',
   proc_chron,
   (
       SELECT billing_amt
       FROM   billing_transaction bt
       WHERE  bt.clinical_transaction_no = btb.clinical_transaction_no
              AND bt.coverage_plan_id = btb.coverage_plan_id
   )                            AS 'Billing Amount',
   balance_amount,
   (
       SELECT MAX(accounting_date)
       FROM   billing_ledger bl
       WHERE  bl.clinical_transaction_no = btb.clinical_transaction_no
              AND subtype = 'pa'
              AND bl.coverage_plan_id = 'standard'
   )                            AS 'Last Payment on Trans',
   (
       SELECT MAX(instrument_date)
       FROM   payment p
       WHERE  p.patient_id = btb.patient_id
              AND p.coverage_plan_id = 'standard'
   )                            AS 'Last Payment on Acct',
   (
       SELECT SUM(balance_amount)
       FROM   billing_transaction_balance btb2
       WHERE  btb2.patient_id = btb.patient_id
              AND btb2.coverage_plan_id = btb.coverage_plan_id
              AND proc_chron <= CONVERT(
                      CHAR(6),
                      DATEADD(YEAR, -1, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, GETDATE())),
                      112
                  ) + '01'
              AND btb2.coverage_plan_id   IN ('standard')
   )                            AS 'Balance'
FROM   billing_transaction_balance     btb
WHERE  proc_chron <= CONVERT(
           CHAR(6),
           DATEADD(YEAR, -1, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, GETDATE())),
           112
       ) + '01'
       AND coverage_plan_id   IN ('standard')
GROUP BY
       patient_id,
       proc_chron,
       coverage_plan_id,
       balance_amount,
       clinical_transaction_no
```

[image]

Comment: Add a `HAVING status='I'`

Comment: Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 19
Invalid column name 'status'.

Comment: You should use joins instead of correlated subqueries. Many of your subqueries are the same table over and over. This could be done with a single select statement.

Comment: In your first subquery that you name 'Status', you need to have a p.case_status = 'I' in that where clause.  Also, look at what Sean mentioned as well.

Comment: This was coded by someone else and I just need an exact variation for a crystal report, so I don't really want to change it if possible. Where in the line would p.case_status = 'i'?

Comment: btw, I don't use Crystal, but in SSRS you can filter out all but Status='I' in the report itself.  So even if the dataset returns with other statuses, you can tell the report to ignore those and only show the "I"'s.  You can probably do that in Crystal too.

Comment: Great idea! I'll try that tomorrow.

Answer (score 1):

Your FROM clause only includes one table (billing_transaction_balance) and that table is referenced by every sub-query.

If you limit the results of that one table to only those with Status='I', it will "blanket" your entire query.   You can do this most effectively with an INNER JOIN to the table that has the Status column in it.

Comment: I kinda get what you are saying, but could you show this in code? Just for the line? Thank you.

Comment: O and that table does not have the status field. It's only in the patient table as case_status.

Comment: FROM   billing_transaction_balance     btb
INNER JOIN patient p
       WHERE  p.patient_id = btb.patient_id
              AND p.episode_id = (
                      SELECT MAX(episode_id)
                      FROM   patient p2
                      WHERE  p2.patient_id = p.patient_id
                  )
AND p.case_status='I'

Comment: Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 15
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'WHERE'.
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 16
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'AND'.

Comment: oops, sorry, I meant to change that first WHERE to an ON, and forgot.  Try this:  FROM billing_transaction_balance btb INNER JOIN patient p ON p.patient_id = btb.patient_id AND p.episode_id = ( SELECT MAX(episode_id) FROM patient p2 WHERE p2.patient_id = p.patient_id ) AND p.case_status='I'

Comment: I'll test it tomorrow and I think that crystal idea will work as well. Thank you.